# usage of left in "There was nothing left of the ghee"

Tags: word-usage

> There was nothing left of the ghee he had bought.

What does *left* do in this sentence? Is it an adjective or a noun?

Comment: You could replace 'left' with 'remaining', and the meaning would be unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

*Left* works like an adjective in this sentence, because it's describing something about the ghee.

Technically, *left* is the **past participle** of "to leave", and the way it's being used here is as a [participle adjective](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-adjectives.html).

Comment: _"The sherry is gone, snd only port is left."_